# How to set default value of Column-Toggle Table Widget for a column?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, widget

I have been toying around with the Table Widget for jQuery Mobile. Is there a way I can set the show-hide status of a column from its table header name via this widget? If there is no such way what will be the best solution for such a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQM doesn't offer an *out-of-the-box* solution for this, therefore, you have to do it through JS. The *column toggle* popup inherits *table*'s `id` followed by `-popup`. You need to target it when `tablecreate` event fires to change *checkbox(es)* property.

Note that only `thead` elements with `data-priority` will be added to *column toggle* popup. Moreover, you will need to target *checkbox(es)* by their *index* using `.eq()` method or `:eq()` selector.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", "#pageID", function () {
   $("#tableID").on("tablecreate", function () {
       $("#tableID-popup [type=checkbox]:eq(1)") /* second checkbox */
           .prop("checked", false)            /* uncheck it */
           .checkboxradio("refresh")          /* refresh UI */
           .trigger("change");                /* trigger change to update table */
   });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/72egjfme/)**

Comment: Nice one Omar +1. Hope you don't mind, but I took your answer and expanded on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468730/jquery-mobile-tables-set-default-view/.

Answer (score 0):

Add the class "ui-table-cell-hidden" to the table header tag.

In this below example, the forth column will be hidden by default.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-priority="1" width="20%">Category</th>
        <th data-priority="2" width="45%">Title</th>
        <th data-priority="3" width="15%">Amount</th>
        <th data-priority="4" width="20%" class="ui-table-cell-hidden">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```