# jQuery mobile tables set default view

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html-table

Does anyone know how to set up a jQuery mobile column toggle table so that when the user loads the page only certain columns are visible by default?  For example columns 1-6 are visible but column 7 is not visible and must be turned on with the column chooser button.

Here is my [project example](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/q1616oa1/)

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-priority="1">Date</th>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th data-priority="2">Dates and Times Needed</th>
      <th data-priority="3">Caregiver In Mind</th>
      <th data-priority="4">Notes</th>
      <th data-priority="5">Comunication</th>
      <th data-priority="6">Unable Reason</th>  <!--  Want this column to be hidden by default -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Comment: here we go, hidden column http://jsfiddle.net/q1616oa1/1/

Comment: kind of works but the column cannot be turned back on in your example.  I would like for the user to be able to make the column visible again by turning it on in the column chooser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not built-in to the widget, so you have to code it yourself.

Here is one way:

This expands on Omars answer here: [How to set default value of Column-Toggle Table Widget for a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191310/how-to-set-default-value-of-column-toggle-table-widget-for-a-column/26192616#26192616) to add an attribute to the column(s) you want hidden.

In the table `<thead>` add a new data attribute for columns that should be hidden at first. In my example `data-hiddendefault="true"` :

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-priority="2">Date</th>
      <th>Client</th>
      <th data-priority="3">Dates and Times Needed</th>
      <th data-priority="1">Caregiver In Mind</th>
      <th data-priority="3">Notes</th>
      <th data-priority="3">Comunication</th>
      <th data-priority="3" data-hiddendefault="true">Unable Reason</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Then add script to the `tablecreate` event. We first get the id of the column toggle popup (table id + '-popup'). Then iterate through all column headers and find the ones that have a data-priority as these are the only ones that appear in the column toggle popup. Now check if the new attribute for hiding the column is there, and if it is, set its checkbox in the popup to unchecked, refresh the checkbox widget, and trigger the change event of the checkbox:

```
 $('[data-mode="columntoggle"]').on( 'tablecreate', function( event, ui ) {
    var id = this.id + "-popup";
    var $cols = $(this).find("thead th");
    var idx = 0;
    $cols.each(function(index){
        if ($(this).jqmData("priority")){                
            if ($(this).jqmData("hiddendefault") == true) {
               $("#" + id + " [type=checkbox]:eq(" + idx + ")").prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh").trigger("change");
            }
            idx++;
        }
    });
});
```

> Here is your updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q1616oa1/4/)**

Comment: @Austin, you are welcome! See my updated answer which uses Omar's setting of the property instead of a click. The problem with a click is that if the column was being hidden by priority on a small screen, the click would actually toggle it back on.